# Pass by reference through multiple functions

Tags: c, pointers

Hey all. I'm working on a project for school where I need to pass a few parameters by reference through multiple functions. I understand how I can pass by reference from where the variables are declared to another function, like this:

```
main() {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  int z = 0;

  foo_function(&x, &y, &z);
}

int foo_function(int* x, int* y, int* z) {
  *x = *y * *z;
  return 0;
}
```

However, how would I pass x, y, and z from foo function to another function? Something like this gives me all kinds of compiler warnings.

```
int foo_function(int* x,  int* y, int* z) {
  *x = *y * *z;
  bar(&x, &y, &z);
  return 0;
}

int bar(int* x, int* y, int* z) {
  //some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use:

```
bar(x, y, z);
```

X, Y, and Z are already pointers - just pass them directly.

Remember - a pointer is a location in memory.  The location doesn't change. When you dereference the pointer (using *x = ...), you are setting the value at that location.  But when you pass it into a function, you are just passing the location in memory.  You can pass that same location into another function, and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything, they're already references.

```
int foo_function(int* x,  int* y, int* z) {
  bar(x, y, z);
  return 0;
}

int bar(int* x, int* y, int* z) {
  //some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In foo_function x y and z are already pointers (int*), so you can do bar(x, y, z).

Answer (score 2):

```
int foo_function(int* x,  int* y, int* z) {
   *x = *y * *z;
   /* x, y and z are pointers to int
      &x, &y and &z are pointers to pointer to int
      bar expects pointers to int, so call bar as:
   */
   bar(x, y, z);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C has no notion of passing by reference. Parameters are always passed by value. However, when using pointers, this *value* is actually a pointer to your actual value.

But what you are doing with

```
foo_function(&x, &y, &z);
```

is actually trying to get an address of the pointer, which is essentially meaningless (you would pass an `int**` instead of an `int*`).

So,

```
foo_function(x, y, z);
```

would be the correct call, as `x`, `y` and `z` are already pointers and you don't need to make the pointing chain any longer :)